# rebuild JDK1.6.8 after some changes

Tags: java, java-6

I want to rebuild JDK1.6 after some changes in currency.java in the java.util package. so how can I do it? is there any compiler or builder to make a custom version of JDK? 
I try $ javac src/java/util/currency.java but it did not work.

Comment: `javac` should do the job, but you have to use it correct. Change the working dir to `src` and then invoke `javac java/util/currency.java`.

Comment: Hope you have good reasons for doing so - at the end your changes will only work if the runtime platform does have access to your customized JRE.

Comment: Which version are you talking about?  There is no version 1.6.8 nor was there a 1.6.0 update 8. It skipped from 7 to 10. The latest version of Java 6 update 27 is also known as 1.6.0_27

Comment: Modifying the classes in the standard Java library is a really bad idea, and maybe it is not even allowed according to Oracle's license terms for the JDK. You should really do everything to solve your problem in a different way before you attempt to do anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not build the whole JDK. Only thing you need is compile your class, put it into a `.jar` and place it in [endorsed folder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) of a JRE.

Answer (score 1):

I found these build instructions for OpenJDK 6 in the source code repository:

> [OpenJDK 6 Build README](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html)

---

**UPDATE** - revisiting this after a couple of years, I came across the following useful blog entry that has links to "Build README" files for a number of Java versions:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/kto/entry/jdk_build_readme_collection

Lets hope it stays there, and stays current!

But yea ... if you have just changed one class, then the "endorsed directory" approach is a better idea; see @kan's answer.

Finally, it is generally a bad idea / undesirable to modify the standard class libraries to make your application work:

- Your code is immediately non-portable.  It will only work on *your private flavor* of Java.
- Each time you upgrade your Java version you have to resync the sources and rebuild.  (The "endorsed" approach is simpler, but you still have work to do on each Java update.)
- There might be legal issues with redistribution of your modified Java.  Talk to an IP lawyer ...